# How to install self signed CA Cert to Trust Store Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.9

Tags: webservice-client

One of our client is using self-signed certificate, So on wget URL below error is displayed

ERROR: cannot verify hostname certificate, issued by “XXXXXXXX”:
  Self-signed certificate encountered.
To connect to hostname insecurely, use ‘--no-check-certificate’.

On doing some research, found that need to trust the certificate as CA is self-signed.

Please let me know how to add the certificate to trust store, 
Os version is: 
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.9 (Santiago)

Answer (score 0):

Later versions of Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 can use the `update-ca-trust` tool to manage the system certificate store (which is also used by wget).  You can use the Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 documentation for guidance:

- [Using Shared System Certificates](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-shared-system-certificates)

The main difference is that on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6, you need to enable this trust store using `update-ca-trust enable` first.